# Does the use of bodybuffers stimulate tendon healing?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, epicondylitis, physiotherapy

I read on http://boxpromag.com/the-power-of-bellecores-bodybuffer/ :

> Stimulating muscle and tendon healing.

Is there any study that confirmed or infirmed that the use of bodybuffers stimulates tendon healing?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

Example of bodybuffer:

[image]